# How to get rid of the 1 pixel white line at the left edge of the window?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I am doing cocoa desktop application and I noticed that there is 1 pixel white line at the left edge which looks pretty ugly for my background.

Is there any way to get rid of it? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you expand the frame of your window's content view to be exactly big enough so there's no white line.